# Plugin/gem for multiselect?

Tags: plugins, rubygems, multi-select

Does anyone have any recommendations for a jquery plugin or ruby gem that I can use to create a pretty multiselect form? The default html multiselect form is shockingly primitive. I want something which allows me to select from a drop-down list, which then adds the text of the selection into the input.

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at any of these:

http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/multiselect/

Personally, I would go with Selectize.js. It's fairly easy to implement and looks beautiful. It sounds like something that might match your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I couldn't find any of these with just a google search. Selectize looks perfect.